# Let $R=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]=\{{a+b\sqrt2:a,b\in\Bbb{Z}}\}$ and the principal ideal $I=(2-\sqrt2)$ in $R$. Is $(2-\sqrt2)$ a proper ideal of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

The concept of proper ideals is confusing me just a little bit. Do I need to prove that $I\neq R$?

There's a second part as well:

b) Rewrite the coset $5 + 3\sqrt2 + I$ from $R/I$ in the form $a + I$, where $a$ is an integer. Try to use the smallest non-negative integer $a$ that you can.

Comment: I'm wondering if for part b, I use $1+\sqrt2 + I = I$?

Comment: For future commenters, we've already discussed how $1+\sqrt 2+I\ne I$ in the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$I = (\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)$ the second factor is a unit, so the ideal is just $(\sqrt{2})$ which is indeed a proper ideal. Now for the second part note that $\sqrt{2}|2j$ for all $j\in\Bbb Z$ so with $5+3\sqrt{2}=2\cdot 2 + 1 +3\sqrt{2}$ what can you conclude?

Comment: I'm looking over my notes and am confused about something. We had an $I=(1+i)$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$. We determined if I was a proper ideal by determining if $1\in I$. I'm not sure why though. Any clue?

Comment: @user21 Because $(1)=R$, so the only way for an ideal to be the whole thing is if it has $1$, this is not an uncommon approach.

Comment: Okay, and if $1\notin I$, then I is a proper ideal?

Comment: @user21 Well certainly if you don't have everything in the ring you have to be a proper subset, that's just set theory

Comment: Yeah. I'm just trying to prove it how we proved it in class.

Comment: @user21 one of the biggest pitfalls in math is trying to adapt the same solution to every problem. If you really must though, you can see how it goes from my answer: In **any** ring $1\in (a)\iff\exists b\in R: ab=1$. Clearly that is impossible as $2-\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)$. Since the second factor is a unit (inverse $\sqrt{2}+1$) this would require $a+b\sqrt{2}$ so that $\sqrt{2}(a+b\sqrt{2})=2b+a\sqrt{2}=1$. But then $a=0$ so that it can be rational and $b$ is an integer. I haven't done it differently, but it's good for you to fill in the details.

Comment: Yeah, i'm just at a basic level right now, so learning how the professor does it is pretty helpful. Then I can expand from there. I see what you're saying though. Since $b$ isn't an integer in that final equation, then $1\notin (2-\sqrt2)$.

Comment: @user21 yes exactly. Then the second part gives you a clear representative, since there are not many smaller positive integers than 1. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not sure if you saw my other comment or not, but could I use that 1+$\sqrt2$ + I = I? We used that in class with $\Bbb{Z} [i]/I$ to get $1+i+I=I \Rightarrow i+I=-1+I \Rightarrow (i+I)^2=(-1+I)^2 \Rightarrow -1+I=1+I \Rightarrow$ $2+I=0+I$ and we got that 2=0 in this quotient ring. Could I do something similar with $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$?

Comment: @user21 No, this is false, $I=(\sqrt 2)$ so $1+\sqrt{2}+I = 1+I\ne I$ because $I$ is not the whole ring. Using that $I=(\sqrt 2)$ is great though, if you look at the answer it tells you immediately that $5+3\sqrt{2}\in 1+I$ so you can switch to the representative $1$.

Comment: Alright. I'm sorry for so many questions. We haven't really discussed representatives. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @user21 no worries, you're making progress, so I don't mind questions at all. Two cosets $a+I$ and $b+I$ are the same if $a-b\in I$, right? The term we use for this is to say that $a$ and $b$ are representatives of the coset. In your case $5+3\sqrt{2}$ is one choice, and $1$ is another.

Comment: So are you saying that $1+I = 5+3\sqrt2$? Earlier you said that you can immediately see that $5+3\sqrt2 \in 1+I$. How do you see that?

Comment: @user21 no, the LHS is a set, and the RHS is an element. I'm saying what I said earlier:  $1+I=5+3\sqrt 2+I$. And look at my answer:  remember $a+I=b+I$ when $a-b\in I$. I showed $5+3\sqrt 2 - 1 = 2\cdot 2 + 3\sqrt 2$ which is in $I$ since $I=(\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, just trying to wrap up part b. I'm looking over everything we've written, but I'm confused about finding an $a$ in $a+I$ such that we can rewrite the coset $5+3\sqrt2 + I$ from  $R/I$.

Comment: @user21 We just said $1+I=5+3\sqrt 2+ I$. So .....

Comment: oh wow. yep. it's too late. my bad. thanks.

Comment: @user21 happens to the best of us. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily checked using the `norm` on $\mathbf Z[\sqrt2]$: by definition,
$$N(a+b\sqrt 2)=a^2-2b^2.$$
This norm is *multiplicative*, i.e. $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbf Z[\sqrt2]$, and $N(1)=1$.

There results an element $x$ is a *unit* if and only if its norm is a unit in $\mathbf Z$. Here $N(2-\sqrt2)=4-2=2$, hence this element has no inverse, and it generates a non-trivial ideal.

An example of a unit is $3-2\sqrt2$, which has norm $1$. Indeed 
$$(3-2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)=9-8=1.$$